# jQuery / javascript - select / change values input fields (ACF / WordPress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, select, advanced-custom-fields

Long story short, I have a long number of conditional custom fields in a WordPress site, which for reasons of length, mean I need to extract the values of currently visible select fields (i.e. not set as disabled) and combine them into a single (hidden) input field which can then be stored for internal reference purposes.

This is all happening in the backend of the WP site with a custom JS file loading.

I'm far from a JS expert, but have managed to get quite close to the desired result, but have hit a snag with the select fields needing to be first selected, and then changed in order to populate the dummy (individual) fields, which are then combined into a single input field.

Could be my entire logic is *WAY* off, but if anyone had any practical tips/guidance, it would be forever appreciated!

Code below with what I'm *attempting* to do - essentially add a dynamic class to each visible select box, then when each of these is updated, send it to an individual text field (input), and at the end, combine all of the individual text fields into one, to act as the internal reference - this is necessary as it's a user generated content site and they'll need to be able to view by the below structure.

```
jQuery("#select_practice select").change(function() {

jQuery('#select_practice select:not(:disabled)').each(function(i){
jQuery(this).addClass('bacon_' + i);
});

jQuery("select.bacon_0").change(function() {
jQuery("#acf-field_5a38ee98b5ff7").val(jQuery(this).val());
});

jQuery("select.bacon_1").change(function() {
jQuery("#acf-field_5a38eeaab5ff8").val(jQuery(this).val());
});

jQuery("select.bacon_2").change(function() {
jQuery("#acf-field_5a38eeb6b5ff9").val(jQuery(this).val());
});

jQuery("select.bacon_3").change(function() {
jQuery("#acf-field_5a38eec6b5ffa").val(jQuery(this).val());
});

jQuery("#select_practice select").change(function() {

jQuery("#acf-field_5a38eecfb5ffb").val(jQuery("#acf-field_5a38ee98b5ff7").val() + " | " + jQuery("#acf-field_5a38eeaab5ff8").val() + " | " + jQuery("#acf-field_5a38eeb6b5ff9").val() + " | " + jQuery("#acf-field_5a38eec6b5ffa").val());

});

});
```

Comment: This is in the backend yes? Is there a reason why you don't update this single custom field (which is hidden from user anyway) through the acf/save_post hook? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

Comment: Yep - backend indeed. I think that could be a go-er, but my concern would be that it could end up storing values that are essentially hidden (due to the conditional appearance of the fields). So, really, all I'd be looking to do, is somehow fill that hidden field with the currently visible values of the select fields...